# How to add a gpg subkey to GitLab

Tags: gitlab, gnupg

GitLab 9.5.0 adds support for checking the gpg signature of commits and display the verification status next to the commit hash ([release note](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/08/22/gitlab-9-5-released/)). This version, however, does not verify commits signed using subkeys ([gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36829), support is planned).

Is it possible to export the subkeys in gpg and convert them into primary keys, such that these primary keys can be added to GitLab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT Oct 2017

Since version 10.1 GitLab has native support for subkeys. You can simply add the
full public key. Commits signed with subkeys show up as 'verified' if the email address of your key has been verified in GitLab.

---

## Orignal answer

**Although the original keyrings should not change, I recommend you to backup all your (public and secret) keyrings first! This solution is rather experimental!**

Create a directory, e.g. `sub2primary`, and change into it, because the following commands will create quite a number of temporary files, which might mess up your home directory. I will assume the following setup

```
frank@7777a258a48e:~/sub2primary$ gpg2 --list-keys
/home/frank/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------------
pub   rsa1024/34171358 2017-08-30 [SC]
uid         [ultimate] Frank <frank@example.com>
sub   rsa1024/320752EA 2017-08-30 [S]
sub   rsa1024/BBA338AD 2017-08-30 [E]
```

on ubuntu 16.04.

## Export subkeys

Firstly, you need to export your keys (public and private, primary and subkey) and break them into individual packets.

```
$ gpg2 --export frank@example.com | gpgsplit -vp pub
$ gpg2 --export-secret-keys frank@example.com | gpgsplit -vp sec
```

These two commands create a couple of files, each corresponds to a single packet. You can inspect the packets with `pgpdump`. We are interested in the files matching `pub*.public_subkey` and `sec*.secret_subkey`. Inspecting one of these files reveals

```
frank@7777a258a48e:~/sub2primary$ pgpdump sec000004-007.secret_subkey 
Old: Secret Subkey Packet(tag 7)(517 bytes)
...
```

that this is indeed a private subkey. If you have multiple subkeys (e.g. one for signing and one for encryption), I'm not sure, how to identify, the correct one. In this example, the packets with `*000004-*` will turn out to contain the keys used for signing. (In doubt pick one, and start over if it was the wrong one.)

**Edit:** `gpg2 --list-packets <file>` shows more information about a packet including the key id. This helps selecting the correct packet.

## Convert to primary keys

Secondly, we need to convert these subkey packets (here `pub000004-014.public_subkey` and `sec000004-007.secret_subkey`) into primary key packets. In order to do this, you need a hex editor (`vim -b` is sufficient) and modify the first byte in each file. Replace the first byte of the public subkey with `\x99`, and the first byte of the secret subkey with `\x95`. If you work with `vim -b`, you can copy the first byte from the primary key files`pub000001-006.public_key` and `sec000001-005.secret_key`. (Don't mix public and secret!)

After this procedure `pgpdump` shows that the keys are now primary ones

```
frank@7777a258a48e:/~/sub2primary$ pgpdump sec000004-007.secret_subkey 
Old: Secret Key Packet(tag 5)(517 bytes)
...
```

## Import primary keys

Next, we need to trick `gpg` to import these broken packets (they don't have a user id, nor a self signature). To do this, simply copy them such that they can be used as keyrings

```
frank@7777a258a48e:~/sub2primary$ cp pub000004-014.public_subkey ~/.gnupg/tmp
frank@7777a258a48e:~/sub2primary$ cp sec000004-007.secret_subkey ~/.gnupg/sec_tmp
```

As shown in the next print out, it is possible to tell `gpg` to use these modified keys.

```
frank@7777a258a48e:~/sub2primary$ gpg2 --no-default-keyring --keyring tmp --secret-keyring sec_tmp --list-secret-keys
/home/frank/.gnupg/tmp
----------------
sec   rsa1024/320752EA 2017-08-30 [SCEA]

frank@7777a258a48e:~/sub2primary$ gpg2 --no-default-keyring --keyring tmp     --secret-keyring sec_tmp --list-keys
/home/frank/.gnupg/tmp
----------------
pub   rsa1024/320752EA 2017-08-30 [SCEA]
```

## Adding user id

The last step consists of editing this key to add a user id.

```
frank@7777a258a48e:~/sub2primary$ gpg2 --no-default-keyring --keyring tmp     --secret-keyring sec_tmp --edit-key 320752EA
```

The subcommand `adduid` will prompt for necessary information. Once you are done, `save`. This adds the user id and signs it automatically.

## Export sub/primary key

Lastly, you can export the new primary key, which is identical to your old subkey. The output can be added to your profile on GitLab.

```
frank@7777a258a48e:~/sub2primary$ gpg2 --no-default-keyring --keyring tmp     --secret-keyring sec_tmp --armor --export
```

You should not use the `tmp` keyrings or this rigged key for any other purposes! You can delete the temporary files, once you have uploaded the key. Commits signed with your usual sub-key will now show up as *verified* on GitLab.

---

Credit: This solution is inspired by http://atom.smasher.org/gpg/gpg-migrate.txt, which uses similar tools to solve a different problem.

Comment: Such a long and advanced instruction yet actually works. Thank you very much. :)
For the step of getting the correct subkey, we can check the key create time.
and for `vim -b` here is one useful command newbie may need `:%!xxd` and `:%!xxd -r`