# Unverified commits in GitLab when using gpg with subkeys

Tags: gitlab, gnupg

I have been testing GitLab and GnuPG to add my signatures to commits. I believed I followed the manual on how to setup both GitLab with a public key and a repository at home to sign commits with private key. The only difference is I use a separate subkey for signatures and encryptions. GitLab correctly recognises all public subkeys and displays certificates as verified. At home, I have assigned the correct ID of a signing subkey to `user.signingkey` as well as trying explicit option `-S<subkey-id>`

Unfortunately, each time I push signed commits, they still appear "Unverified". I checked the ID of a signing key at each commit and the subkey-ID seems correct and email addresses also match, in both GitLab and GPG certificates. The email address used in GitLab is verified. I tried `user.name` for GitLab credentials but it did not help, either. I was wondering what else can be unrecognised by GitLab.

I find little information regarding this issue. Usually, others follow a procedure on website creating default GPG certificates without additional subkeys and `Unverified` commits most likely appeared due to mismatch between email addresses. I also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965240/how-to-add-a-gpg-subkey-to-gitlab/45965241?r=SearchResults#45965241), which explaines how to merge subkeys into one key. However, GitLab should work with subkeys without any extra preparation. There [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230336/git-uses-wrong-subkey-for-signing-commits-with-gpg-key) did not help me, either.

Answer (score 1):

I had that issue, after I imported my GPG keys from a second PC, so the imported keys were **NOT** trusted on my second system.

Run `gpg --list-keys` and check if your line with the email hast the `[ultimate]` state.

If not, then set the **trust** with `--edit-key`

```sh
gpg --edit-key name@domain.tld
trust
5
yes
save
```

Answer (score 1):

Signing with subkeys is currently still very buggy on GitLab and does not work for some. Please also see the associated feature-request [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/36829), especially the latest answers. It seems that it still has not been fixed.